# Why do I have to redraw the image after changing the canvas size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a small meme generator that allows the user to use any URL he/she wants and change the size of the image.  Everything's working the way it should, but I noticed, if there's already an image on the canvas and the user decides to change the canvas size, the image is "erased".  Why does this happen and is there a way to prevent it from happening?

**JS**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("main");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var open_image = document.getElementById("open_in_new_window");
    var change_img_size = document.getElementById("change_img_size");
    var get_canvas_width = canvas.getAttribute("width");
    var get_canvas_height = canvas.getAttribute("height");
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        console.log("Image drawn");
    }

    open_image.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var user_img = document.getElementById("input_url").value;
        image.src = user_img;
        console.log(user_img);
    })

    change_img_size.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var set_canvas_width = document.getElementById("change_img_width").value;
        var set_canvas_height = document.getElementById("change_img_height").value;
        console.log(set_canvas_width, set_canvas_height);
        canvas.setAttribute("width", set_canvas_width);
        canvas.setAttribute("height", set_canvas_height);
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="main" width="450" height="550"></canvas>
<div id="user_actions">
    <input type="text" id="input_url" placeholder="Input image location." />
    <input type="text" id="change_img_width" placeholder="Change image width." />
    <input type="text" id="change_img_height" placeholder="Change image height." />
    <button id="open_in_new_window">View Image</button>
    <button id="change_img_size">Change Image Size</button>
</div>
```

Here's a [Pen](http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/VeGVzv)

Comment: That's just the way canvas works -- it auto-erases when resized. Most often, you can just redraw the content on the newly sized canvas, but if you need the previous content you can save the content to an imageObj (or another canvas) with `context.toDataURL` before resizing the canvas and then `drawImage` the saved content back to the newly sized canvas.

Comment: I'm assuming I would need to do the drawImage method at the end of my `change_img_size` click handler?

Comment: Thanks for your deleted answer @markE, I'd upvote it if I could.  Your solution saved my bacon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-canvas-element):

> When the user agent is to set bitmap dimensions to width and height,
>   it must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Reset the rendering context to its default state.
> 2. Clear the scratch bitmap's hit region list and its list of pending
>      interface actions.
> 3. Resize the scratch bitmap to the new width and height and **clear it** to
>      fully transparent black.
> 4. If the rendering context has an output bitmap, and the scratch bitmap
>      is a different bitmap than the output bitmap, then resize the output
>      bitmap to the new width and height and clear it to fully transparent
>      black.

You can try [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) before resizing the canvas, and then [putImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) after, but I'm not sure if the same-origin policy will allow it.

If you don't need to change the intrinsic size of the canvas, you can change `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height`, this will not erase the canvas.