# Canvas state lost after changing size

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to resize a canvas, but when I do, the context gets reset, losing the current `fillStyle`, transformation matrix, etc. The `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` functions didn’t work as I initially expected:

```
function resizeCanvas(newWidth, newHeight) {
    ctx.save();
    canvas.width = newWidth; // Resets context, including the save state
    canvas.height = newHeight;
    ctx.restore(); // context save stack is empty, this does nothing
}
```

After researching for a while, I can’t seem to find a good way to save and restore the canvas context after resizing. The only way I can think of is manually saving each property, which seems both messy and slow. `ctx.save()` doesn’t return the saved state either, and I don’t know of a way to access the context’s stack.

Is there a better way, or am I doomed to use something like this:

```
function resizeCanvas(newWidth, newHeight) {
    let fillStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
    let strokeStyle = ctx.strokeStyle;
    let globalAlpha= ctx.globalAlpha;
    let lineWidth = ctx.lineWidth;
    // ...

    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;

    ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    ctx.globalAlpha= globalAlpha;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: See [Why do I have to redraw the image after changing the canvas size?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208498/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox Thanks, that makes sense. But I didn't see any solutions for saving the context state, just for restoring the image. It seems that there isn't a better way the just storing every property, resizing, then restoring them one by one.  I hate to do it, but if it's the only way...

PS. Thanks for the edits, it's much easier to understand now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found this somewhat annoying and I'm very interested to see if there are other solutions to this. I'd also like to see a reason as to *why* the state has to be reset and the state stack cleared when the canvas is resized. Really it's unintuitive behavior that you wouldn't expect and even [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) doesn't mention it, so it's probably pretty easy to make this mistake.

**The absolute best way is to restructure your code in such a manner that all draw operations can be redone after the canvas is resized** since you're gonna have to redraw everything anyway, you might as well be setting all the ctx states after you resize anyway. (i.e. make and utilize a 'draw' function that can be called after you resize the canvas)

If you really want to keep the state then I'd recommend making your own save/restore state stack and perhaps a resize function while you're at it. I'm not gonna judge you and say it's a bad idea...

Let's say I wanted to resize the canvas to the exact width and height of some text before drawing the text.

Normally I would have to set the font for the text first, then measure the text, then resize the canvas, but since resizing the canvas resets the state, I'd then have to set the font again like so:

```
ctx.font = "48px serif"
width = ctx.measureText('Hello World').width
canvas.width = width
ctx.font = "48px serif"
```

As an (admittedly over-complicated) workaround, I'd save and restore the state using my custom save-restore functions before and after resizing, respectively.

And yes, I do see the irony in replacing one extra line of code with around 30 or so extra lines of code in this particular example.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  , stack = []

function save(ctx){
  let state = {}
  for(let property in ctx){
    if(property == 'canvas')
      continue
    if(typeof ctx[property] == 'function')
      continue
    state[property] = ctx[property]
  }
  stack.push(state)
}

function restore(ctx){
  let state = stack.pop() || {}
  for(let property in state){
    ctx[property] = state[property]
  }
}

function resize(ctx, width, height){
  save(ctx)
  ctx.canvas.width = width || canvas.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = height || canvas.height;
  restore(ctx)
}


//////////////    EXAMPLE    ////////////////


let index = 0
  , words = ["Our", "Words", "Are", "Dynamic"];

(function change(){
  let font_size = ~~(Math.random() * 150 + 16)
  let word = words[index]
  index = (index + 1) % words.length
  
  ctx.font = font_size+"px serif"
  ctx.textBaseline = "hanging"
  ctx.fillStyle = "white"
  resize(ctx, ctx.measureText(word).width, font_size)
  ctx.fillText(word, 0, 0)
  
  setTimeout(change, 750)
})()
```

```css
canvas{
  background-color : orange
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah, the code is for a library, so I'd like to have the resize function as "user friendly" as possible, even if that includes a janky workaround. Your loop solution is perfect for that, though. I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of that, lol. I was going to just hard code them >.<

Thanks for the time and effort, also your snippit looks amazing XD

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer no longer works because some properties are deprecated and hence give runtime error when trying to set deprecated properties.
Here's a fix for Khauri MacClain's answer.

```
function save(ctx){
    let props = ['strokeStyle', 'fillStyle', 'globalAlpha', 'lineWidth', 
    'lineCap', 'lineJoin', 'miterLimit', 'lineDashOffset', 'shadowOffsetX',
    'shadowOffsetY', 'shadowBlur', 'shadowColor', 'globalCompositeOperation', 
    'font', 'textAlign', 'textBaseline', 'direction', 'imageSmoothingEnabled'];
    let state = {}
    for(let prop of props){
      state[prop] = ctx[prop];
    }
    return state;
}

function restore(ctx, state){
    for(let prop in state){
      ctx[prop] = state[prop];
    }
}

function resize(ctx, width, height){
    let state = save(ctx);
    ctx.canvas.width = width || canvas.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = height || canvas.height;
    restore(ctx, state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to take a partially-drawn canvas -- generated by a library, and so not really possible to resize before all the draw commands were issued -- and expand it to add some text next to it.  There's a deleted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35208082/26286) by @markE that helped me out.  See, you can make a new canvas element of arbitrary size, and "draw" the old (smaller) canvas onto it:

```
const libCanvas = myLib.getCanvas();
const newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = MY_FONT;
newCanvas.width = libCanvas.width + ctx.measureText(myStr).width;
ctx.drawImage(libImage, 0, 0);
ctx.font = MY_FONT; // Changing width resets the context font
ctx.fillText(myStr, libCanvas.width, libCanvas.height / 2);
```

Now `newCanvas` is as wide as the old canvas, plus the width of the text I wanted to draw in, and has the contents of the library-generated canvas on the left side, and my label text on the right side.